# SQL Comparing Dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, compare

in a database table I have made a date attribute but I have set it's type to varchar and not Date.
My question is, will I still be able to compare such dates in a SQL Query?

Dates in my DB are stored in this format:

> dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

I have to do a SQL Query in PHP that looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM DBtable
WHERE DBname='$name' AND date>='01/01/2015' AND date<='01/09/2015';
```

I would appreciate an example how to do this.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: why did you make them a varchar to begin with? I Guess you can always convert them to a date before comparing

Comment: You can cast your `varchar` to a `date` if it is in the correct format.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using WAMP for home testing. Database that i use is phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert/cast to compare:

```
SELECT *
FROM DBtable
WHERE DBname='$name' 
  AND CAST(date AS DATETIME) >='2015-01-01' 
  AND CAST(date AS DATETIME)<='2015-01-09'
;
```

Much better to store values as the appropriate data types to avoid this inefficiency.   You could also use `DATE` instead of `DATETIME` if you want to compare without the time component.  Syntax and available datatypes vary by database, so the above may need adjustment.

Update:  Since you're using MySQL, you can use the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM DBtable
WHERE DBname='$name' 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d/%c/%Y') >= '2015-01-01' 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d/%c/%Y') <= '2015-01-09'
;
```

Comment: I have tried this but sql query always returns nothing. It seems like comparing of the dates isnt working as expected

Comment: Might depend on the database, as I mentioned.  The comparison above in SQL Server works because the hard-coded date is converted to `DATE`/`DATETIME` implicitly since it's being compared to that data type on the other side.

Comment: @user1926550 See updated answer, every database handles date formats differently, MySQL can't handle your format for `CAST()` so you need to provide it a format with the string to date function.

Comment: Great man! It works now. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can cast a `Varchar` to a `Date`. Here is an example:

```
SELECT
CAST(date_column AS DATETIME) 
FROM 
TABLE_NAME
```

In your case it might look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM DBtable
WHERE DBname='$name' 
AND CAST(date AS DATETIME) >='01/01/2015' 
AND CAST(date AS DATETIME) <='01/09/2015';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast or convert a `varchar` to a `date` or `datetime` before you do any comparisons.

But you'd have to do it *every single time* you compare the date to something.  That's because the following comparisons are all true if you compare them as `varchar`:

```
'2/1/2015' > '1/5/2016'
'25/1/2015' > '15/2/2015'
'11/1/2015' < '3/1/2015'
```

You'll also need to convert if you want to pull out some time-based aspect of the dates, such as any records where the hour was before `8:00 AM`.  There is no easy way to do that if your date is a `varchar`.

And that assumes that the value in your database can always be parsed into a date!  If an empty string or some other kind of data gets in there, `CONVERT(datetime, MyColumn)` will fail.

So I would strongly recommend that you change your column to be a `date` or `datetime`.  It will make your life much easier.